# Database design: how to avoid serialization when data structure is not static

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I've recently been confronted with the need to design a database. Since this is my first time, I thought I'd better ask for some advice to make sure I'm building on solid foundations.

**Goal**

I'd like to store objects (POD structures best thought of as multi-maps) in an
SQL database for storage and querying. The objects' contents as well as its 'structure' are continuously modified. The database will be accessed intensively through both queries and updates.

**Use Case**

First, each object should have a unique identifier.

Second, different type of objects exist. For example, ObjectA is an instance of ClassA. ClassA can have attributes A1, A2, A3, etc. As a result, ObjectA can (but isn't required, NULL is allowed) have values for these attributes. However, each of these attributes may have more than one value, ie: `ObjectA.A1="foo"` and  `ObjectA.A1="bar"` are both possible. The number of attributes of ClassA can change. For simplicity's sake, attributes can only be added, not removed.

Third, attributes are not specific to one class, ie: objects of ClassB can also have attributes A1, A2, etc. Thus `ObjectB.A1="foo"` is also possible. I'm not sure whether this changes anything, but I have a feeling it might in a design where each attribute corresponds with a table.

Finally, the following pseudo-queries and actions must be supported:

- Get all the objects of type ClassA with attribute A1 equal to "bar".
- Get all the attributes of ObjectB.
- Add an attribute A4 to objects of type ClassA.
- Add an object of type ClassC which has attributes A1="foobar", A2="bar".

**Limitations**

First, I want to avoid serializing the data, so multiple values in a single column are out of the question. The database should be normalized and the data structures should be atomic. The database will be queried very frequently, so I cannot afford wasting time trying to implement a complex query mechanism. I will end up re-inventing the wheel (probably a square one as well).

Second, I cannot use any prior knowledge of an object's internal structure as this will only become available at run-time. For example, in the use case above, the attributes are not known before-hand. So while I have thought of having a design where each attribute is a table, I cannot figure out how to get all the attributes of an object in such a set-up.

**Environment**

I'm using SQLite 3.7, C++.

**Question**

What would be an appropriate, flexible database design that meets the requirements of the described problem?

Any help, pointers or tips leading to useful insights or a solid design are very welcome.

Thanks!

ps: I have only basic theoretical familiarity and limited practical experience with relational databases, certainly no prior professional experience. I have been reading up on the subject the past week and have grasped some of the concepts which I think will be relevant to my case (normalization, foreign keys, etc), but I'm still going through my book at this moment.

Comment: If you don't know the attributes of an object, you can't design a normalised relational database for it. Needing to be able to define new objects and new attributes at run time is going to be very painful.

Comment: This is _potentially_ the time to use an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).  However, I'd attempt to nail down more of the requirements first, as they're a bit of a pain to work with.

Comment: the EAV model is something to look at.  You may also go for a complex instantiation of a metamodel and resulting physical model as found in some commercial products (like Enterprise Elements)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - An EAV model does seem like something I should investigate further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this is your first time out, and your project is as significant as it seems,  you might want to invest the time and effort to learn the fundamentals from the ground up.  CJ Date and many other authors have books and on line tutorials that can take you through the fundamentals.  They are excellent works.

There are some fields within IT that are dominated by almost complete adhocracy.  Not so database design.  To begin with, EF Codd laid the groundwork on a very solid mathematical basis some 42 years ago, and the basic model has held up very well over time.  There has been progress, but almost no backtracking.  And very little change for the sake of change.

SQL has likewise enjoyed a lot of stability over its long lifespan.

Next, trial and error in database design can be enormously costly.  There are dozens of cases where unfortunate choices made by newbies have ended up costing millions in data investments that didn't pan out.

Trial and error has its place.  Tips and tricks have their place.  Answers on SO have their place.  But so does formal learning.